# Hide form and display div on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to hide the form in `div id="first"` and show the `div id="second"` when the submit button is pressed. Below is the code I'm using, but it isn't working. The result is a 'quick' hide of `div id="first"` and a 'quick' show of `div id="second"` before the page returns to its original view.

Can someone please help me correct this? Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    $("#first").hide();
    $("#second").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<div id="first" class="1" style="display:">
  <form action="/student/webdesign/2015/4th/04_50/tinker/hideDiv/hide.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <p>

      <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <br>
      <input type=submit formmethod="POST">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="second" class="2" style="display:none">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: because the form submits and the page reloads. Do you want the form to actually submit? If not, cancel the default action. If you do, than you would need the serverside to set the state of the elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its probably because the default event is being executed on when the form is being submitted. Give this a try.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#first").hide();
            $("#second").show();
        });
    });
```

Give this a read as well - https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/